# Help with the integral for the variance of the sample median of Laplace r.v.

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, asymptotics, definite-integrals

When we draw $n$ samples of [Laplace-distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) random variable such that $n=2k+1$ and the location parameter is zero, the median $x$ (or the $k$-th order statistic) has the following p.d.f.:

$$f_m(x)=\frac{n!}{(k!)^2}2^{-n}\frac{1}{b}e^{-(k+1)|x|/b}(2-e^{-|x|/b})^k$$

where the p.d.f. of the underlying Laplace distribution is given as $f(y)=\frac{1}{2b}e^{-|y|/b}$.

The formula for p.d.f. of the median stems from the usual method of characterizing the distributions of order statistics and is found as equation (2.5.10) in [Kotz's volume on Laplace distribution](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Laplace_Distribution_and_Generalizat.html?id=cb8B07hwULUC).  There is another formula for the case when $n$ is even, but we shall not be concerned with it for now.

I am interested in the variance of the sample median.  Since $f_m(x)$ is symmetric about $x=0$, I can get rid of the absolute value and write it as follows:

$$\sigma^2_m=\frac{n!}{(k!)^2}2^{-n}\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-(k+1)x/b}(2-e^{-x/b})^kdx$$

What I need is to reduce the following definite integral to a more manageable form:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-(k+1)x/b}(2-e^{-x/b})^kdx$$

For fixed $k$ this is fairly easy integral to solve.  However, I am interested in asymptotics of variance $\sigma_m^2$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and $b$ is a linear function of $\sqrt{n}$, and thus need a solution for an arbitrary $k$.

Any ideas?

Comment: You've tried binomial expansion already?

Comment: Just to understand the question correctly: $b= \alpha \sqrt{n}$?

Comment: @J.M. Binomial expansion didn't come to mind for some reason.  Great idea, will try it in the morning.

Comment: @Fabian Yes, that's correct (it may be more complicated in the problem I am actually trying to solve, but for now I can just assume $b=\alpha\sqrt{n}$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand now. You want to find
$$\sigma^2=\frac{n!}{(k!)^2}2^{-n}\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{\infty}\!dx\,x^2e^{-(k+1)x/b}(2-e^{-x/b})^k$$
where $n=2k+1$ and $b \sim \sqrt{n}$ for $n,k \to \infty$. Let us first use the change of variable $y=x/b$. We then find
$$\sigma^2= b^2\frac{n!}{(k!)^2}2^{-n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\!dy\,y^2e^{-(k+1)y}(2-e^{-y})^k.$$

We will use the [method of steepest decent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent) to figure out the asymtptotic behavior of $\sigma^2$ for $k,n \to \infty.$ Let us first rewrite the integral as
$$ \int_0^\infty\!dy\,y^2e^{-(k+1)y}(2-e^{-y})^k =
\int_0^\infty\!dy\, y^2 e^{-y} e^{- k f(y)}, \qquad f(y) =y-\log(2-e^{-y}). $$
The function $f(y)$ assumes its maximum at $y=0$. Thus, the integral is asymptotically dominated for values of $y$ close to $0$. To this end, we expand $f(y) = y^2 +O(y^3)$ and we  have
$$\int_0^\infty\!dy\, y^2 e^{-y} e^{- k f(y)} \sim
\int_0^\infty\!dy\, (y^2 -y^3 +O(y^4)) e^{-k y^2} = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{4 k^{3/2}} - \frac{1}{2k^2} +O(k^{-5/2}). $$

Additionally, we use that (see [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)) $$\frac{n!}{(k!)^2} \sim2 \binom{2k}{k} \sim 2 \frac{4^k}{\sqrt{\pi k}} = \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi k}}.$$

Together, we have (with $b \sim \alpha \sqrt{n} \sim 2 \alpha \sqrt{k} $)
$$\sigma^2 \sim \underbrace{4 \alpha^2 k}_{b^2} \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi k}} 2^{-n} \frac{\sqrt\pi}{4 k^{3/2}} = \frac{\alpha^2}{k}. $$

Comment: By the scaling arguments, it should be proportional to $b^2$.

Comment: @Sasha: you are right (for the variance), but there is a $1/b$ which the OP pulled out of his integral -> see his post. I added the post to make it clear that I refer to the last integral in his post.

Comment: @Fabian Right, unfortunately,that dependence on $k$ is pretty important.  Maybe J.M.'s suggestion of using binomial expansion will work to solve that.

Comment: @M.B.M.: I didn't understand in the beginning that $k$ depends on $n$ as well. I changed my answer. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Looking now a bit more careful at where the integral came from, I believe I just made a pretty long calculation to confirm the central limit theorem in the end...

Comment: @Fabian I don't think you confirmed the CLT, as $b=\alpha\sqrt{n}$ implies that the variance of the Laplace r.v. increases linearly with number of samples $n$.  You have however confirmed my rough calculation of this using Mathematica which also indicated that variance of the median decreases with $n$ even when variance of the r.v.'s increases linearly with $n$.  Note that the median is the MLE of the location parameter of Laplace distribution. Also note that for a Gaussian, the MLE of location (sample mean) does NOT decrease with $n$ if variance increases linearly with $n$. This is strange...

Comment: @Fabian Now a couple of technical questions about your answer: How did you go from $\int_0^\infty\!dy\, y^2 e^{-y} e^{- k f(y)}$ to $\int_0^\infty\!dy\, (y^2 -y^3 +O(y^4)) e^{-k y^2}$?  I am sorry if that's a dumb question, but I am not familiar at all with the method of steepest descent...  Also, did you mean "the integral is asymptotically dominated for values of $y$ close to 0" instead of "the integral is asymptotically dominate for values of $y$ close to $y$"?

Comment: You are right: I meant dominated by values close to 0.  What I did to get the asymptotic form is to take the lowest order term $y^2$ of $f(y)$ and kept it in the exponent the rest of the integrand (whatever is not in the exponent and higher order terms originating from the exponent) I simply expanded in a Taylor series.

Comment: @Fabian Ok, I see what you did.  I really would like to *understand* the justification for the steps you took to analyze the integral asymptotically.  However, I am not familiar with the method of steepest descent.  Is there an article on it that someone with rudimentary knowledge of multi-variable calculus can understand?  I think I'll post a separate question about this though...

Comment: The justification is simple: you can convince yourself easily that each term in the Taylor series proportional to $y^n$ leads (after integration) to a term proportional to $k^{-n/2}$. So higher terms in the Taylor series lead to terms which are subdominant.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first set $b=1$, and recover it later using scaling. For $X \sim \mathrm{Lap}(0,1)$
$$
   f_{X_{k:2k+1}}(x) = \frac{k+1}{2^{2k+1}} \binom{2k+1}{k+1} \mathrm{e}^{-(k+1)|x|} \left(2-\mathrm{e}^{-|x|}\right)^k = \frac{k+1}{2^{2k+1}} \binom{2k+1}{k+1} \sum_{m=0}^k \binom{k}{m} 2^{k-m} (-1)^m \exp\left(-(m+k+1)|x|\right)
$$
Thus
$$
  \mathbb{Var}\left(X_{k:2k+1}\right) = \frac{k+1}{2^{2k+1}} \binom{2k+1}{k+1} \sum_{m=0}^k \binom{k}{m} 2^{k-m} (-1)^m \frac{4}{(k+1+m)^3} = \\ \binom{2k+1}{k+1} \frac{2^{1-k}}{(k+1)^2} \cdot {}_4F_3\left( \left.\begin{array}{cccc} -k & k+1 & k+1 & k+1 \\
   & k+2 & k+2 & k+2 \end{array} \right| \frac{1}{2} \right)
$$
[image]

The sequence above satisfies an inhomogeneous recurrence equation of rank $3$:
[image]

This recurrence equation allows to determine the large $k$ asymptotic behavior. There are fewer undetermined coefficients, because $X_{k:2k+1}$ converges to a degenerate random variable for large $k$, meaning that the variance must vanish in this limit:
$$
   \mathbb{Var}\left(X_{k:2k+1}\right) = \frac{c_1}{k}\left(1+ \mathcal{o}\left(k^{-1}\right) \right) + \frac{c_2}{k^{3/2}}\left(1+ \mathcal{o}\left(k^{-1}\right) \right) 
$$
The following plot indicates that $c_1>0$:
[image]

Sequence acceleration  suggests that value of $c_1$ is close to $\frac{1}{2}$:
[image]